# How to ignore multiple spec files in playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright

in my config i have 3 projects, one runs tests for a specific acc type using one login, the other runs tests for another login, and now ive just added a 3rd project that has to run tests for a specific browser.

Problem is, I need the second project to also ignore tests from the third project as well as the first.

My config looks like this:

```
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Basic Users',
      testMatch: /.*limited.spec.ts/,
      use: {
        baseURL: process.env.URL,
        screenshot: "only-on-failure",
        video: "retain-on-failure",
        storageState: 'login1.json', 
        headless: true,
        viewport: { width: 1536, height: 850 },
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      } 
    },
    {
      name: 'Admin Users',
      testIgnore: /.*limited.spec.ts/,
      use: {
        baseURL: process.env.URL,
        screenshot: "only-on-failure",
        video: "retain-on-failure",
        storageState: 'login2.json', 
        headless: true,
        viewport: { width: 1536, height: 850 },
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      } 
    },
    {
      name: 'Comment Tests',
      testMatch: /.*comments.spec.ts/,
      use: {
        baseURL: process.env.URL,
        screenshot: "only-on-failure",
        video: "retain-on-failure",
        storageState: 'login2.json', 
        headless: true,
        channel: 'chrome',
        viewport: { width: 1536, height: 850 },
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      } 
    }
  ]
};
export default config;
```

I basically need to ignore the comment tests from running in the admin project

Comment: Can't you use `testMatch` in each project to match against the relevant spec file and then remove all use of `testIgnore`?

Comment: the admin tests have multiple spec files separated in different folders, my solution was to group everything that needed to be ignored into a certain folder, and my test ignore will just ignore the folder in the admin tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [grep](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-grep) or [grepInvert](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-grep-invert) to skip over certain tests in projects.
So something like this might work:

```
{
  name: 'Admin Users',
  grep:  /.*limited.spec.ts/,
  grepInvert: /.*comments.spec.ts/
  use: {
    baseURL: process.env.URL,
    screenshot: "only-on-failure",
    video: "retain-on-failure",
    storageState: 'login2.json', 
    headless: true,
    channel: 'chrome',
    viewport: { width: 1536, height: 850 },
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  }     
},
```

Maybe you need to adapt the regex to match your needs.